# How to change inner color of glyphicons in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an empty-star button like this,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
</button>
```

When I click it, I want the inner color to change to yellow like shown here - http://s21.postimg.org/3qwgsnrcj/star.png

How can we achieve this using Bootstrap and Javascript?

Here's a link to what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/refatelefi/edit?html,output

Comment: @Paulie_D It's possible, but it's a bit nasty. What OP has to do: add another star (with JS) when clicked on the button. See https://jsfiddle.net/066bkv87/

Comment: I meant with CSS...anything is possible with JS

Comment: @Paulie_D Check. Luckily OP can use JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A glyphicon is like a character. You can change it's color by changing the color property of the span style.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
</button>

.glyphicon-star-empty {
   color: yellow;
}
```

However, the icon you picked is not full, so you can't change the inside as you asked. I would recommend using the "glyphicon glyphicon-star" instead.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>

.glyphicon-star {
   color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a full icon and color then redraw the outside via text-shadow with black or any other color.

```css
.glyphicon-star {
   color: yellow;
  text-shadow:0 0  black,0 0  black,0 0  black,0 0  black,0 0  black;
}
.bis.glyphicon-star {
  text-shadow:0 0 1px  black,0 0 1px  black,0 0 1px  black,0 0 1px  black ;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star bis"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: why do you repeat the same text-shadow rule several times?

Comment: @dandavis to mimic the stroke wich is only avalaible with SVG. text-shadow produces only blurs, if you pile them, it is morelike a stoke then :), just use one instead and see difference. You can add as many as you want or need (size, orientation colors, ..)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about getting it exactly similar to your star.png, while you can use javascript to set css color property on the button or you might want to use background-color property. 
Here is a simple demo
http://jsbin.com/netufaruxa/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
<body>
 <button id="myBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="refresh">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
 </button>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function colorChange(){
  if(document.getElementById("myBtn").style.color==""){
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.color="yellow";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.color="";
  }
}
(function() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", colorChange);
})();
```