# Fill in color of UTF-8 star

Tags: css, css-shapes

How can I use CSS to fill in the background color of a UTF-8 star (☆)? I tried using this, but it only changes the border color:

```css
.rating {
  color: #f70;
}
```

```html
<p class="rating">&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;&#9734;</p>
```

Comment: quiet similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377918/how-to-change-inner-color-of-glyphicons-in-bootstrap/36378074 if not a duplicate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use a solid star, like http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/PaulBGD/pen/reXWvX

```css
 #star {
   font-size: 128px;
   color: yellow;
   /* Some sort of border */
   text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 }
```

```html
 <span id="star">&#9733;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `&#9733;` or `&#x2605;` UTF8 characters?

```css
div {
  padding: 2px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div span {
  position: relative;
}
div span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  color: gold;
}
div span:hover ~ span:before {
  content: "\2606";
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&#9734;</span>
  <span>&#9734;</span>
  <span>&#9734;</span>
  <span>&#9734;</span>
  <span>&#9734;</span>
</div>
```

And by using pseudo elements, you can even add functionality such as a 5 star rating system.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rating-system with star (in CSS + JavaScript) only using css shapes and javascript.
This code works with other charset too!

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```